# disable dropdownlist items in gridview based o selection

Tags: c#, asp.net

In asp.net c#, I have dropdownlist inside gridview. The Dropdownlist has same set of values in all rows of gridview. If some items are selected in one row, the selected items should be disabled in other rows. How to do it?

Comment: show us what you tried

Comment: What do you mean by " If some items are selected in one row"....
if you are using dropdown ...........

Answer (score 0):

May below code will help you.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlItem" runat="server" 
   onselectedindexchanged="ddlItem_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>

protected override void OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e)
{
   string strSelectedValue = this.SelectedValue.toString();

   foreach(foreach (GridViewRow row in grid.Rows)
   {
      //Write logic to disable item
     ((DropDown)row.FindControl("ddlItem")))

   }
}
```